# Allow Module to access class instance variables without specifying instance name

Tags: ruby

I thought it is useful to allow module methods to access instance variables of the class that includes it. I thought it is brittle to specify an instance variable name in a module (if instance name is `@local`, writing `@local` in the module method) as it creates a coupling between the module and class. Therefore, I implemented the following:

```
module MyModule    
  def set_class_instance(proc)
    @class_inst = proc
  end
  def module_print_instance
    puts "Module: instance var #{@class_inst.call}"
  end
end

class MyClass   
  include MyModule
  def initialize(var)
    @local = var
    set_class_instance Proc.new {@local}
  end
end
```

I was wondering if this is overkill. I just want to pass a pointer to the instance variable to use to my module. Is it necessary to wrap it in a block to do this?  Is this bad Ruby coding practice?

Comment: You don't have a class instance variable anywhere.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? If you need to access MyClass's instance variable in a module's method, you can do it directly like `def module_print_instance; puts "instance var: #{@local}"`. It's because by including with `Module.include` module methods become part of a class which includes it. See docs of `Module.append_features` for details.

Comment: sawa, maybe the Mick is not aware of `@@` class instance variables and so mistakenly named the variable `@class_inst`?  Mick, see "Class Variables" in the "Classes, Objects, and Variables" chapter of [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)